# IEnumerable<IDataRecord> comparison

Tags: c#, linq

I've got the following method :

```
public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> DbQueryToArray(string connectionString, string sql)
    {
        if (null == sql)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sql));

        string SqlCString = connectionString;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SqlCString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            if (connection == null)
                throw new Exception("Db's down.");

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        yield return reader as IDataRecord;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (connection != null)
                connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

So I'm collecting the Db tables data into 2 separate arrays:

```
var table_1 = DbQueryToArray(SQL_Conn_String.ConnString, query1);

var table_2 = DbQueryToArray(SQL_Conn_String.ConnString, query2);
```

What would be the most efficient way and simplest to output the difference/s between the 2 arrays ?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you delegate that work to the database and form *one* query that will give you the differences?

Comment: Thanks nvoigt. Can that be done if the tables reside on 2 different databases?

Answer (score 1):

First we need a way to compare the records.

```
public class DataRecordComparer : IEqualityComparer<IDataRecord>
{
    public bool Equals(IDataRecord x, IDataRecord y)
    {
        var a = new object[x.FieldCount];
        var b = new object[y.FieldCount];

        x.GetValues(a);
        y.GetValues(b);

        return a.SequenceEqual(b);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IDataRecord obj)
    {
        var values = new object[obj.FieldCount];
        obj.GetValues(values);

        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            foreach (var item in values.Where(x => x != null))
                hash = hash * 23 + item.GetHashCode();

            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can use Except to get the differences.

```
var comparer = new DataRecordComparer();
var diff = table_1.Except(table_2, comparer).Concat(table_2.Except(table_1, comparer));
```

For performance reasons you might want to do this in the database instead and only bring back the differences. You would use a similar approach, except you do not need the comparer.

```
select a,b,c
from tbl1

except

select a,b,c
from tbl2

union all

select a,b,c
from tbl2

except

select a,b,c
from tbl1
```

(I did not have time to test the code, so there might be some issues, but at least it should point you in the right direction.)